# Getting hardware accelerate working on nouveau

Tags: linux, hardware-acceleration, nouveau

I've just got a new gpu from nvidia and am trying to get hw accelerated video decoding working. I've tried bunch of thinks I found on the internet but nothing helped, the `Decoded capabilities` iin vdpauinfo's output come out empty.

Sadly using nvidia's proprietary drivers is not an option for me, which means I need to get this working with nouveau.

My card is GeForce GT 1030 (GP108, NV138), is it even possible to get that working?

Comment: @greywolf have you tried they're website: Optimize Your Game Settings

GeForce Experience takes the hassle out of PC gaming by configuring your game’s graphics settings for you. Don’t know what texture filtering level to set in Overwatch? Not to worry. NVIDIA taps into the power of the NVIDIA cloud data center to test thousands of PC hardware configurations and find the best balance of performance and image quality. Then it automatically configures personalized graphics settings based on your PC’s GPU, CPU, and display.
https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/geforce-experience/#grd/

Comment: @greywolf The drivers page is here: https://www.geforce.com/drivers

Comment: You configured vdpau? https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Hardware_video_acceleration#Configuring_VDPAU . Read more - https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=275686 . If you still decide to use a proprietary driver, read - https://ultra-technology.org/software_settings/mpv-nvidia-driver-with-high-quality/

Comment: As mentioned in the question I cannot use nvidia's proprietary drivers. And I have the vdpau configured, vdpauinfo works, just shows only not supported in the video decoding section :/